# libssl1.0.0 won't let me install anything

Tags: skype, debian

I've been having the same issue with my computer for a while now and it's really been bugging me. It all started when I installed Skype about a month ago. Also, I apologize, I'm not actually using Ubuntu, though I would if I had the choice :P. I'm using Debian: SteamOS more specifically. I posted 3 different questions on the Debian user forums but got no answers. I was hoping maybe you guys could help instead considering I don't think this is a problem unique to Debian.

Essentially, whenever I try to install most programs, I keep getting this error:

```
desktop@steamos:~$ sudo apt-get install zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4) but 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 is to be installed
libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1) but 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I was reading around on here and found an answer for someone so I tried it. They said to simply redownload libssl1 and dpkg it. But this is what happened.

```
desktop@steamos:~$ sudo apt-get download libssl1.0.0:i386
[sudo] password for desktop: 
Get:1 Downloading libssl1.0.0 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 [3,008 kB]
Fetched 3,008 kB in 5s (528 kB/s) 
desktop@steamos:~$ sudo dpkg -i '/home/desktop/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1_i386.deb' 
(Reading database ... 114464 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 (using .../libssl1.0.0_1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1_i386.deb) ...
De-configuring libssl1.0.0:amd64 ...
Unpacking replacement libssl1.0.0:i386 ...
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--install):package libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is at a different version (1.0.1e-2+deb7u4)
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:amd64 (--install):package libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:i386 is at a different version (1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
libssl1.0.0:i386
libssl1.0.0:amd64
```

So any ideas how to fix this? I get the break error every time I try to install anything that uses libssl1 and it prevents me from using any unzipping tools (besides tar), WINE, and even dwarf fortress :(

EDIT: after running

```
sudo apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0:i386
```

I get

```
desktop@steamos:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0:i386
libssl1.0.0:i386:
  Installed: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1
  Candidate: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 0
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steamos/ alchemist/main i386 Packages
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steamos/ alchemist_beta/main i386 Packages
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/internal/steamos/ alchemist/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u4 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u3 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
```

and after running

```
sudo apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0
```

I get:

```
desktop@steamos:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4
  Candidate: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1
  Version table:
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 0
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steamos/ alchemist/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/steamos/ alchemist_beta/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://repo.steampowered.com/internal/steamos/ alchemist/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.1e-2+deb7u4 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u3 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I'm going on a wild guess here, but what does `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` return?

Comment: When I do that, I says:
    i386

Comment: There goes my theory. I was guessing that your distro release wasn't multi-arch, but it seems it is.

Comment: :( Any other ideas, man? I tried removing libssl1 so it could just update and get the right packages, but when I try apt-get remove libssl1, it says it can't find the package.

Comment: The package name is `libssl1.0.0`. The dots matter.

Comment: I just noticed something: Can you run `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0:i386` and `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0` (no `sudo` required here)? Is there one repo in one list that isn't in the other list? If you're unsure, update your main question with the output.

Comment: Thanks @saiarcot895, I updated the post with the apt-cache policy output. That was after trying apt-get remove with the full name; libssl1.0.0

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing Debian and SteamOS repos, and I'm sure that's a big no-no. You should remove the Debian repositories from your sources.list file. To fix you other issue, use:

```
sudo apt-get install -f libssl1.0.0:i386=1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1 libssl1.0.0:amd64=1.0.1e-2+deb7u4+bsos1
```

This will force both packages to have the same version.

Answer (score 1):

You have a newer version of the library for i386, but an older version of the library for amd64. Therefore, you are getting conflicts since you can't (and probably shouldn't) have different versions of the same library (but different architectures). Doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` will update all packages and install any necessary dependencies.

Comment: I tried that, and this is what I get.

    desktop@steamos:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    [sudo] password for desktop: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     skype:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Answer (score -2):

Download libSSL 1.0.0 i386 and amd64 [from Ubuntu Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libssl1.0.0), then go to the downloaded files folder, execute in terminal "sudo dpkg -i file_name" for both downloaded files.